# how to apply condition to xsl key

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to display xml data through xslt.
I would like to show the output as follow

```
// Description  Level         ActivityName ActivityID
// ===========  ============  ============ =======================
// Main Entry   Start         Main Entry   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
// Hello World  Information   Main Entry   {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
// alpha        Start         alpha        {aa5a5b9c-4b24-43af-9f49-32656385e17d}
// Hello world  error         alpha        {aa5a5b9c-4b24-43af-9f49-32656385e17d}
// Hello world  Transfer      alpha        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

Description is the application data text and the level is Sub Type Name and activity Name will be the description. This activity name will be same until the level value is start. I have to repeat the same description value under activity name till you get an other start in level column.

## XML

```
<root>
<E2ETraceEvent>
    <System>
        <SubType Name="Start">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Main Entry </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent>
    <System>
        <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Hello World!</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent>
    <System>
        <SubType Name="Start">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="aa5a5b9c-4b24-43af-9f49-32656385e17d" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>alpha </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent>
    <System >
        <SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
        <Correlation ActivityID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>Hello World!</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
</root>
```

## XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <div>
          <div>
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Level</th>
                  <th>Activity Name</th>
                  <th>Activity ID</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="/E2ETraceEvent">
                  <xsl:variable name="level_key" select="/E2ETraceEvent[contains(key,'kSubtypeName')]/value"/>
                  <xsl:variable name="level">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./SubType/@Name"/>
                  </xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:variable name="activityID">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./Correlation/@ActivityID" />
                  </xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:variable name="description">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./ApplicationData/text()" />
                  </xsl:variable>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="$description"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$level = 'Start'">
                          <xsl:value-of select="$description"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                          <xsl:value-of select="$description" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="$activityID"/>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does the output you show match your input example? There are only 4 `E2ETraceEvent` elements in your input, but your output shows 5 rows, which I find very confusing. I also don't understand your description of the problem: what do you mean when you say "key"? Your title says "XSL key", but you are **not** using the `xsl:key` element, or the key() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only guessing here, but I think you want to do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Activity Name</th>
            <th>Activity ID</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="E2ETraceEvent">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="ApplicationData"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="System/SubType/@Name"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <!-- description from the last 'Start' - including the current node -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="((. | preceding-sibling::E2ETraceEvent)[System/SubType/@Name='Start'])[last()]/ApplicationData"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="System/Correlation/@ActivityID"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this would return:

[image]

Comment: I believe last one should be Main entry not alpha based on ActivityId

Comment: @cilerler I believe you are misled by a poor example.

Comment: as far as my undestanding, he is trying to display [TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.xmlwritertracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx)  activity log, so it doesn't make sense if the last one is alpha.  I believe he wants to associate each `activityId` with `level==start` (if there is one) and display the `activityName` for those acitivityIds in the future rows (at least this is how [SvcTraceViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) works)

Comment: @cilerler I can only go by the OP's description of their requirements, not yours. If you feel you have a better answer, you're welcome to post it. I will not change mine, esp. not after OP has accepted it.

Comment: of course, I was just sharing what I'm thinking.  If I would provide better answer here, probably wouldn't wait to post it :)